# Why, when I right-click a single file and go "Scan with Microsoft Defender", does it start scanning my entire system?

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus, windows-defender

I've done it numerous times now, with the same result every time. It didn't use to do this weeks or months ago.

It doesn't just scan that file, but my entire damn machine. Which means it never ends, but just goes on and on. It's doing a "custom scan" of my entire machine, when I only want to scan one file.

Why has it changed its behaviour like this? In practice, it means I have no idea if it thinks that the file contains malware or not, because it just never stops since it's scanning every file on my machine which is going to take an eternity.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* normal for *Defender* to scan a few *system* files before it checks the file in question, but that preliminary scan should take no more than a minute. There are a few reasons Defender might perform a full scan:

- If a full scan has not been performed in a week or two, *Defender* will start one, if you request another scan.
- If a file cleanup has been performed, removing results of the last scan, *Defender* sees that as an unscanned system.

BTW, you might try a third-party tool, such as Winitor's [pestudio](https://www.winitor.com/), which uses the *Explorer* context menu to submit files to [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/), to check for malware by 70 or so engines, including Windows *Defender*. Or just submit the file to VirusTotal using your browser.